# Font size inconsistancy between browsers on mac

Tags: html, css, macos, fonts

In the following example, it's a navigation bar. Its elements are variable in width, the sum of their width is the width of their container, `ul` element.
The issue is, each element has the same width on all windows browsers, the sum of their width is 379px. But on mac each browser seems to render the font slightly different, causing the width to either increase or decrease, thus the last element wrap to the second line.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;padding: 0;}
ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type: none;}
.nav {
    width:379px;
}
.nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #0099ff;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>asdf</li>
        <li>qwer</li>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>testing test</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is, how to guarantee each element's width on all browsers by just specifying the font size.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a fixed-width div plus padding size is tricky when working with text. It's unlikely you'll be able to get a string to render exactly the same size on all major browsers and platforms. Though you can get pretty close; here are some suggestions.

- Specify `px` values rather than `pt` or `em`. Such text will render at the same size regardless of device resolution, and will still scale properly when zooming in and out
- Use a very common font, or a web font. You can use Font Squirrel to strip down a version of a specific font you'd like to use
- Explicitly set the `font-smoothing` method
- Use a computed CSS property to offset the `letter-spacing` by a fraction based on the amount the resulting div width differs from the target. This will be accurate, but also complex and less compatible
- Use JavaScript to do the above calculation instead, resulting in more compatible code
- Render some PNGs beforehand, or server-side at runtime

Here's some sample code illustrating one way to get a more consistent cross-platform Arial text render.

```
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, validate your HTML. You have some issues there, like a missing DOCTYPE. I also recommend HTML5BOILERPLATE to get a lot of normalization done.

Next: why do you make the width dependant on the font size? Wouldn't it be better to make the font size static and set a certain static width to your elements?
If you are scared that this behaviour will lead to reading problems on small sceens (mobile devices), you should read about responsive layouts. They make use of media queries to use alternative CSS based on certain rules.

Comment: Well, thank you for the suggestion.  Though, DOCTYPE is not the issue here.
And the width is dependant on the font size to avoid difference in padding size on the text sides.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't get it work, it would be fairly simple to load a .png of the text with a transparent background.